# Read remote text file in android

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android development so forgive my ignorance.
I need to be able to read some text from a remote webpage at say 15 minute intervals. The webpage itself contains just one word with no html tags or formatting. If this is possible if someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Sure, try the following

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("yoursite.com/thefile.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str = in.readLine();
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Put the above in the `run()` method of a `TimerTask`. Then use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: If it needs to be read if your app's Activity is backgrounded or killed, you'll want to use a a Service with an Alarm instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: You might also want to consider separating this out into a different thread so it won't lock up your UI while the data is being read.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to put "in.close()" in a finally {} clause, to make sure it always closes